# Write WATIR equivalent Code for the given xpath

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

I am trying to write the watir code for the given xpath, but it's clicking the wrong button, the given below xpath works perfectly.

```
@browser.element(xpath: "//div[text()='#{locator.strip}']/../following-sibling::div/input/following-sibling::div").click
```

WATIR Code

```
@browser.div(text: locator.strip).parent.following_sibling(tag_name: 'div').input.following_sibling(tag_name: 'div').click
```

I am trying to click the select list button to open the option, but it wrongly clicks the select list which is present below my targetted select_list. Can anyone help me where I go wrong? If you see the below pic, It has to open the title, but it's opening the ID type.

[image]

**Update**

```
<div class="v-csslayout v-layout v-widget spml-cell v-csslayout-spml-cell spml-property v-csslayout-spml-property span4 v-csslayout-span4">
  <div class="v-caption v-caption-spml-value v-caption-uppercase v-caption-editable" id="gwt-uid-43" for="gwt-uid-44">
    <div class="v-captiontext">Title</div>
  </div>
  <div role="combobox" class="v-filterselect v-widget spml-value v-filterselect-spml-value uppercase v-filterselect-uppercase editable v-filterselect-editable v-filterselect-prompt" id="ClientDetails/Title">
    <input type="text" class="v-filterselect-input" autocomplete="off" id="gwt-uid-44" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-43" tabindex="0" dir="" style="width: 281px;">
    <div class="v-filterselect-button" aria-hidden="true" role="button"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML structure?

Comment: @JustinKo I have updated the HTML for one element.

Comment: if you set `Watir.logger.level = :info` it will show you the XPath it generates for that element and you can compare.

Comment: @titusfortner Okay, but do you see am I making any mistake while I convert that xpath into WATIR equivalent? I am converting correctly, right? If so, something is wrong in WATIR code, no?

Comment: I can't tell exactly from your snippet, but isn't the element you want the div with the combobox role? e.g. `browser.div(role: "combobox")`?

Comment: With that many attributes available for each of the elements there shouldn't be any reason to resort to using parent or following sibling...

Comment: @titusfortner Justin answer works perfectly but I would say WATIR is not making our work easier in anyway instead it's making the work tougher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the XPath and Watir code is how they interpret the "text" of an element:

- In the XPath, `//div[text()='#{locator.strip}']` says that the **very first text node** of the `div` must equal the locator.
- In Watir , `div(text: locator.strip)` says that the **concatenation of all text nodes** of the `div` must equal the locator.

As a result, you end up starting from different elements:

- XPath starts from `<div class="v-captiontext">Title</div>`
- Watir starts from `<div class="v-csslayout v-layout v-widget spml-cell v-csslayout-spml-cell spml-property v-csslayout-spml-property span4 v-csslayout-span4">`

This difference results in Watir navigating to a different parent and then jumping over to the adjacent field.

Knowing this, if you wanted to be as close to your XPath as possible, you could add the class locator to the initial div:

```
@browser.div(text: locator.strip, class: 'v-captiontext').parent.following_sibling(tag_name: 'div').input.following_sibling(tag_name: 'div').click
```

However, assuming there isn't any other text in these elements (ie exactly like the sample), Watir is already giving the top-level element. Therefore you could simply do:

```
@browser.div(text: locator.strip).div(class: 'v-filterselect-button').click
```

Comment: It would be great catch! Brilliant. But this should be a bug. People those knows Xpath tend to write xpath like I did. So that has to work that way to exactly locate the element not the parent element which encloses the inner element.

Comment: hi, both of them are not working, it's throwing this error `timed out after 60 seconds, waiting for #(Watir::Div: located: false; {:text=)"Title", :tag_name=)"div"} --) {:adjacent=):following, :index=)0} --) {:class=)"v-filterselect-button", :tag_name=)"div"}) to be located`

Comment: For your first xpath, it throws this exception `timed out after 60 seconds, waiting for #(Watir::Div: located: false; {:text=)"Title", :tag_name=)"div"} --) {:tag_name=)"div", :adjacent=):following, :index=)0} --) {:tag_name=)"input"} --) {:tag_name=)"div", :adjacent=):following, :index=)0}) to be located`

Comment: Consider an element that has multiple text nodes - eg `<div class="v-captiontext">A<b>B</b>C</div>`. Would you expect `div(text: 'A')` to match this? For me, I don't think it should - I would want `div(text: 'ABC')` to be what matches.

Comment: Sorry @Rajagopalan, the original answer was wrong as I had modified the HTML incorrectly to make it easier to verify elements (as click won't tell me anything). Please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Worksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss Now! Thank you very much! But I would like to say WATIR is not making our work ease in any way instead it's making our work more difficult compared to writing xpath.

Comment: That might be true in some cases. If you have ideas to make things better, I'm always happy to talk through it. Though, if you need to write such complicated XPaths, one could likely argue that the best approach is actually to make better application code/HTML.

Comment: But making application code is always not in the hand of a Automation tester. Consider this, If I write this, //div[text()='something'] is locating that exact division , So WATIR has to the same when I write `b.div(text: 'something')` but if it includes the parent div then it's not correctly going with xpath. User may tend assume wrong. And more than that, we can check the (continued)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222099/discussion-between-rajagopalan-and-justin-ko).